# Request more permission from Facebook Session returns an error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I use this in my `onSessionStateChange`

```
session.requestNewReadPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("user_photos")));
```

and i get this error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made
>   to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

here is the full code of the `onSessionStateChange` callback.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if (state.isOpened())
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            m_lblWelcome.setText("You are logged in :)");
            session.requestNewReadPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("user_photos")));

            //Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, getCurrentLoggedInUser);

        }
        else if (state.isClosed())
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            m_lblWelcome.setText("Why did you leave :(");
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the onActivityResult() method on your current Session when asking for more permissions:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Why is that? what does onActivityRestult has to do with getting more permissions ?

Comment: So i have added the code but it did not help ... any other suggestion ?

Comment: If you did not add call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(context, requestCode, resltCode, data); Your request would not be completed, and in next request you will get this error as you mentioned.